# Different page from a browser and wget

Tags: linux, dns, wget, http, certbot

EDITED TO REMOVE OBSOLETE EXAMPLES

I have a very curious case that has dumbfounded me.

I was trying to get a certificate from letsencrypt and I was consistently getting errors that certbot is unable to validate the domain (I was using `--webroot` option).

I even tried placing a file in the `.well-known` directory to test it and I got very peculiar results. When using my browser to access the file I got the contents of the file... however when using `wget http://myaddress.tld/.well-known/...` I got a different page that I have never seen before.

What can be causing this case of two different results from the same web address?

Comment: different User-Agent

Comment: Can't confirm you get the text file in a browser. If you have a login cookie set, the server could spot that even when you go through a proxy.

Comment: @IporSircer what does this mean and how does it help me?

Comment: DNS giving inconsistent answers for IPv4 and IPv6?

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason...

DNS had different physical servers in **IPv4** and **IPv6** records (A and AAAA) and one place (my browser) was using IPv4 while all the other servers I checked used IPv6, including certbot.